# Excel Pop up box when cell value changes to yes

Tags: excel, vba

Good Evening,

Im wondering how i would get this code to work on a range of cells from N7 to N51?

The pop up box works perfectly but only in the referenced cell of N7 i need this to work on every cell from N7 to N51 so that when each cells value changes the pop up box appears. So if change Cell N8 the box appears and so on. The reason for this is not every cell will change and i just need the pop up box to appear on cells that change etc.  Heres the code ive managed to bring together.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$N$7" Then

    MsgBox "If Date Entered In Attempt 3 -Send Text Message Chaser Email" & VBA.vbCrLf & "If Date deleted from Attempt 3 ignore this message" & Target, vbOKOnly, "Warning"


End If


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

JD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) method.

This doesn't check the value of the changed cell, and you might want to also check whether more than one cell was changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N7:N51")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "If Date Entered In Attempt 3 -Send Text Message Chaser Email" & VBA.vbCrLf & "If Date deleted from Attempt 3 ignore this message" & Target, vbOKOnly, "Warning"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked a charm and is exactly what i was after. Thank you.